# Swift set struct property with name in variable

Tags: swift, struct, codable

After loading a json in a codable struct I'd like to change values dynamicly. I already can change a targeted value this way:

```
let setThisValue = 0.6
setConfig.instrumentsConfig[0].effects![0].feedback!.setValue(value: setThisValue)
```

Given these structs:

```
struct InstrumentConfig: Codable{
    let trackId: String
    var effects: [Effects]?
}

struct Effects: Codable{
    
    let effectName: String
    var dryWetMix: ValueAndRange?
    var resonance: ValueAndRange?
    var cutoffFrequency: ValueAndRange?
}

struct ValueAndRange: Codable{
    var value: Double
    var range: [Double]
 
    mutating func setValue(value: Double){
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Since I'm loading data which can contain various property names I'd like to iterate trough all properties and set the correct one. I do know the index of the property i.e. resonance has index 2.

This is how this unknown function could be called, where ????[2] is the unknown part

```
let setThisValue = 0.6
let effectPropperty: String = "feedback"
let effectProppertyIndex = 2

setConfig.instrumentsConfig[0].effects![0].????[2]!.setValue(value: setThisValue)
```

Thank you for any ideas about this.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to implement this, but most of them are going to use `@dynamicMemberLookup` at some point. A simple way is like this:

```
@dynamicMemberLookup
struct Effects: Decodable {
    let effectName: String
    var dryWetMix: ValueAndRange?
    var resonance: ValueAndRange?
    var cutoffFrequency: ValueAndRange?

    private static let keyMap = [
        "dryWetMix": \Self.dryWetMix,
        "resonance": \Self.resonance,
        "cutoffFrequency": \Self.cutoffFrequency,
    ]

    subscript(dynamicMember key: String) -> ValueAndRange? {
        get { Self.keyMap[key].flatMap { self[keyPath: $0] } }
        set { Self.keyMap[key].map { self[keyPath: $0] = newValue } }
    }
}
```

A key requirement is that all of your dynamic keys need to be of the same type (`ValueAndRange?` in this case).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. If I change Codable in Decodable, the json will not load. I've tried adding both but that gave the error "Redundant conformance of 'Effects' to protocol 'Decodable'" And second, how would I call this subscript?

Comment: You can make it Codable instead if you like. I don't like to force things to be Encodable if I'm not going to Encode them. You'd call this exactly like your question suggests.  `...effects[0].dryWetMix?.setValue(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Array method firstIndex(where:) :

```
let index = setConfig.instrumentsConfig[0].effects?.firstIndex {
$0.effectName == effectProperty
```

}